# Field validations at frontend or backend? Which is better?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm developing a login and registration form using angular-6 as frontend and nodeJs as backend.
So just want to know which is better, field validation in Angular or in Node?

Answer (score 7):

It's best to do it on both, frontend and backend. The backend validation is for security (frontend can be easily faked). The frontend validation is for better usability (direct feedback without a roundtrip to the server).

Answer (score 0):

@RajanKumar I will suggest doing field validation on the frontend side because Front-end validation (javascript) can easily be bypassed. It should only be used to improve the "user experience". It reduces the load on the server

Use Back-end validation if you required to check the data is coming from frontend side is valid or not for example at the time of signUP check where the email address is already exists or not.

Comment: I got your point Sneha. But if the user manipulates the data by using developer tools, it will insert invalid data to our database if we don't check at the back-end.
Suppose we are using required=true in some of the tags. But if the user removes it with developer tools, they can fill empty data to our database.
As it comes to authentication, the back-end call is required.
I really appreciate your time and help.
looking forward to having more question for you as I just started learning Angular. :p

Answer (score 0):

Frontend validation is good for a better user experience. But Backend validation is more close to the server and it is important for security.